# Exponentially decaying bound for $K_{1}(x)$

Tags: asymptotics, bessel-functions

I know that a bound for the Bessel function of the second kind of the first order is given by
$$K_{1}(x)<\frac{1}{x}.$$
But it also holds that
$$K_{1}(x)\sim\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}e^{-x}$$
for $x\to+\infty$.

The first bound is very loose when approaching infinity, so I was wondering if there is a bound valid on the entire $(0, +\infty)$ but which decays exponentially at infinity.

Comment: Doesn't the latter bound already decay exponentially at $\infty$, and is already tighter than the first bound for $x$ close to $0$ as well? [Indeed as far as I can see now, the second bound is tighter than the first possibly everywhere on the positive real number line...]

Comment: It is [known](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.40.ii) that for $x>0$, $$
K_1 (x) = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2x}}} e^{ - x} \left( {1 + \frac{3}{{8x}}\theta (x)} \right)
$$ with $0<\theta (x)<1$. Replacing $\theta$ with $1$ yields an upper bound for $K_1(x)$.

Comment: @Mike The second one is an asymptotic approximation and not a bound.

Comment: @Gary thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for. One thing is not obvious to me: how to see that $\theta (x)$ is bounded by $1$.

Comment: @SpuriousMatemagician It follows from the linked section in the dlmf. The error is bounded by the first neglected term of the asymptotic expansion and has the same sign. The first neglected term is $\frac{3}{8x}$.

Comment: The part I was not getting is the bound of the term $|R_{l}$ Doesn't it have a term like $e^{3/(4x)}$? Maybe I don't get this part.

Comment: @Gary I am dumb. I was reading the subsequent paragraph. Thanks a lot

Comment: $$ K_1(z) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z\cos(t)}{(t^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\,dt $$
equals, by the self-adjointness of the Laplace transform,
$$ K_1(z) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{u^2}{1+u^2} J_1(uz)\,du.\tag{1} $$
It follows that Tricomi's inequalities for the asymptotic behaviour of $J_k$ algo give equivalent inequalities for $K_k$.